# Docker container granularity: SOA or monoliths?

Tags: architecture, docker, components

Currently I have a Java web app that is backed by half-a-dozen-or-so microservices, where each microservice communicates with 1+ backing resources (DBs, 3rd party REST services, CRMs, legacy systems, JMS, etc.). Each one of these components lives on 1+ VMs. Hence the architecture is as follows:

- `myapp.war` lives on both `myapp01.example.com` and `myapp02.example.com`

  - Connects to `dataservice.war` living on `dataservice01.example.com` and `dataservice02.example.com`, which connects to `mysql01.example.com`
  - `myapp.war` also connects to `crmservice.war` living on `crmservice01.example.com`, which connects to `http://some-3rd-part-crm.example.com`

Now say I wanted to "Dockerify" my whole app architecture. Would I write 1 Docker image for each type of component (`myapp`, `dataservice`, `mysql`, `crmservice`, etc.) or would I write one "monolithic" container containing all apps, services, DBs, message brokers (JMS), etc.?

I'm sure I could do it either way, but the root of my question is this: **Are Docker containers intended to house/contain a single app, or are they intended to represent an entire *environment*, comprised of multiple interconnected apps/services?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker philosophy definitely dictates to create separate Dockerfiles for every application, service or backing resource you have and then [link](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) them, for example.

You can use Docker Compose to run different Docker containers together: [Django](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) and [Rails](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) examples.

Also, tools like [kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) or [ECS](http://aws.amazon.com/ecs/details/) allow you to manage full lifecycle and infrastructure of your entire environment, including auto scaling, load balancing, etc.